# compatibility and complications with AJAX on older computers?

Tags: jquery, ajax

While a website animated using AJAX and JQuery should always have a non-animated version for browsers that don't support the script, what are the issues with older computers that do support the scripts?

I ask because of AJAX's dependence on the client side. Does a computer's speed (processor, RAM, video RAM) determine how fast an AJAX script will perform? Is it just the internet connection? Or if a browser supports the AJAX/JQuery scripts, regardless of the computer itself, will it perform well?

Comment: Processing is done server side. AJAX performs a request. Manipulating data returned from the request to place into the DOM is not part of AJAX.

Comment: it will perform on p4 easily and there is not older processor than p4 using currently  ...so don't worry about it

Comment: How old? Single-core processors running Windows XP, for example. Is it safe to say then that a site animated using AJAX/JQuery will be supported by 90%+ of the internet user community in USA and Canada?

Comment: Yes, the processor being slow won't stop the animation from working, it just won't be as pretty, if it has any effect on it at all.

Comment: @KevinB perhaps you can put that comment into an answer with a little more explanation, so your answer can be accepted and others could benefit from it?

Answer (score 0):

The processor being slow will not impact whether or not the animation works or your ajax requests are successful or even the amount of time that it takes for either to complete.

Animations will still complete in approximately the same amount of time (give or take a few ms), they will just be more choppy. Think of it as running an animation in IE6 vs IE9.

Ajax requests will still happen just as fast as they do in a fast computer because their speed is network related, not CPU related. If the user is on a slow network, the request will be slow. The processing of the data from the request may be slow, but it still should work.